# Error: Error initializing task ValidatePackageReferences

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I've tried rebuilding and cleaning all of my projects, but I keep getting the following error:

Error: Error initializing task ValidatePackageReferences:  (MyProjectName.iOS)

It also appears with the Android project.

I've got everything up-to-date and have restarted Xamarin and my computer.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: did u fix the problem??

Comment: the only thing I was able to do was restart my computer. Restarting VS itself did not work.